# Using metaprogramming for message queue management

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I am implementing a communication mechanism in `C++` that is designed with message queues and message classes. That is, an abstract parent `Message`, and class `Communication`, where there exists a method `Communication::send(Message&)`. The class `Communication` sends the message to an appropriate message queue `message_queue`, that is determined by the message's type. 
(That is, for `Msg1` it sends to a queue `Queue_Msg1` and `Msg2` is sent to `Queue_Msg2`)
Each message type would be created as a derived class from `Message`.

Mainly, I am interested in having the creation of queues be automatic. That is, if I decide to add a new message type class `newMsg`, the process of adding the message queue `Queue_newMsg` won't require code changing in the `Communication` class, such as code creating queues for each message type.

As this can be done in compile-time (In compile time, all derived message classes are known and so the message queues that are needed), I'm trying to think of some metaprogramming solution, but didn't manage to find such.

Using some known MPL, such as `boost/mpl`, how can I achieve the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pack your types into a list:

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct type_list {};
```

Use that list and parameter pack unpacking to create a `std::array` of queues.  If you want the queues themselves to be specifically typed, they will need to be in a `tuple`.

The list above implies a bijection between index and type.  Have instances of each type return the index, which you can use to pick up the queue (in the array, easy -- in a `tuple`, requires more work).

An `index_of` traits class, to find the index of a type `T` in a `type_list<Ts...>`:

```
template<typename T, typename list, typename=void>
struct index_of {};

template<typename T, typename T0, typename... Ts>
struct index_of<T, type_list<T0, Ts...>, 
                typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, T0>::value>::type
               > :  std::integral_constant<size_t, 0> 
{};

template<typename T, typename T0, typename... Ts>
struct index_of<T, type_list<T0, Ts...>, 
                typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T, T0>::value>::type
               > :  std::integral_constant<size_t, 
                                   index_of<T, type_list<Ts...>>::value+1> 
{};
```

Possibly implement a CRTP based "message helper" that implements both `GetTypeIndex` and ensures that your type is in the central message list.

This requires C++11, in C++03 it is much harder, and more limited.  A C++11 compiler will also handle 100s of types without doing much extra template metaprogramming (with serious metaprogramming, 1000s or more, at least in theory), while a C++03 compiler even with a robust metaprogramming library may be limited to 10s of types.

Note that an advantage to this approach is you can, in theory, do away with the abstract parent class entirely, or at least with the `sendMessage( message const& m )` interface (why should people be allowed to send abstract messages?).  You could be only allowed to send an actual concrete message type.  This again requires some more work (you create pack-expanded inheritance tree that uses CRTP to get ahold of the queue).

```
struct MessageBase {
  virtual size_t GetTypeIndex() const = 0;
};
template<typename D, typename List>
struct MessageHelper: public MessageBase {
  static_assert( std::is_base_of< MessageHelper<D,List>, D >::value, "MessageHelper<D> must be inherited from by D" );
  D* self() { return static_cast<D*>(this); }
  D const* self() const { return static_cast<D const*>(this); }
  virtual size_t GetTypeIndex() const final override {
    return index_of<D,List>::value;
  }
};

struct A_Queue {
  std::deque< std::unique_ptr<MessageBase> > data;
};

template<typename type_list>
struct MessageQueues;

template<typename... Ts>
struct MessageQueues<type_list<Ts...>> {
  std::array< A_Queue, sizeof...(Ts) > queues;
  void Enqueue( std::unique_ptr<MessageBase> msg ) {
    size_t index = msg->GetTypeIndex();
    queues[ index ].data.push-back( std::move(msg) );
  }
};
```

for a seriously rough draft implementation.

Comment: Thank you! I've adopted some of the things you mentioned, and although not going for a complete metaprogramming solution, I thought of an in-between solution that uses both templates and runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than depending on metaprogramming you can register at runtime the different message types. The registry could create a vector of queues and provide unique identifiers to minimize the cost of lookup, or if you don't quite care about that you can always use a map from some id into the appropriate queue.

While I would not recommend it, if you really want to write a complex template solution you can take a look at type lists. All the building blocks you need are in *Modern C++ Design* by Alexandrescu (typelist, how to build hierarchies out of them, together with some fancy template tricks).

Comment: How would you suggest to implement the runtime registry? Obviously a communication class would include a vector of queues, but how can I do so while minimizing the code change?

Comment: @Edgepo1nt: In `main` you can register each message type with the communication class. If you have some identifier (message type?) that can be used to index it could directly be used to index into the vector of queues. If that is not possible, you could generate an id (first open position) during registry. Whenever a new message of that type needs to be send/received you use that index to access the communication class' queue.